# The script below worked fine until I decided to send the output to email

Tags: powershell-3.0

This script should get the `Error` and `Warning` events from the event log and send them in an email. Currently the email is received with no body content. Any ideas why the body is blank?

```
$computers = Get-Content "C:\Source\MorningCheck.txt"; 

$smtpServer = "mail.mycompany.local"
$smtpFrom = "system@mycompany.com"
$smtpTo = "emailrecipient@mycompany.com"

$style = "<style>BODY{font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt;}"
$style = $style + "TABLE{border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;}"
$style = $style + "TH{border: 1px solid black; background: #dddddd; padding: 5px; }"
$style = $style + "TD{border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px; }"
$style = $style + "</style>"

foreach ($computer in $computers) {
     $MessageSubject = "Error log for server:" + $Computer
     $message = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage $smtpfrom, $smtpto
     $Message.Subject = $messageSubject
     $message.IsBodyHTML = $false
     $message.Body = Get-EventLog -ComputerName $Computer -LogName System -EntryType "Error","Warning" -After (Get-Date).AddDays(-1) |
                     Select-Object MachineName, Index, TimeGenerated, EntryType, Source, InstanceID
     $smtp = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
     $smtp.Send($message)
}
```

Comment: Could be there are no Error/Warning events? Or alternatively there are too much of them and you hit some size limit. Did you try printing the message body before sending?

Comment: I ran the script before trying to send the results to email and there were several events (maybe 25?) but the text of some of them was rather long. how would I go about viewing the text before sending the email?

Comment: Try `Get-EventLog ... | Select-Object ... | Out-String`.

Comment: Worked great Ansgar! Thank you very much. I will have to read up on the Out-String command.